# Swiper.js - few problems

Tags: html, swiper.js

I need help configuring Swiper.js.
I have a problem with fixing the position of thumbnails if I change the size of the browser window. If I do not change its size, the spears almost work.
The second problem is how can you control the magnification? It currently works on 1 click. Is it possible to start from 1 to 3 every 1 step?

The third problem - if I have two separate instances on the page (one as modal), how can the modal be transferred to the selected item from the default selected slide?

(google translate)

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
 var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  autoHeight: false,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  // slidesPerView: 4,
  slidesPerView:'auto',
  loopedSlides: 3,
  freeMode: true,
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
  direction: 'vertical',
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  slideToClickedSlide: true,
  on: {
      resize: function () {
         /* do something */
         // galleryThumbs.navigation.update();
         console.log("resize");
      }
    }
  });
  var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
   autoHeight: false,
   
   //zoom: {
    //maxRatio: 3,
  //},
   preloadImages: false,
   lazy: true,
  spaceBetween: 0,
  observer: true,
  observeParents: true,
  grabCursor: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: galleryThumbs
  }
  });

  
 $('.zoomIn').click(function(){
   galleryTop.zoom.in({
    zoom: true,    
   }); 
 })
 $('.zoomOut').click(function(){
   galleryTop.zoom.out({
    zoom: true
   }); 
 })




 // $(".wrapper").hide();
  
 $("#modal").on('click', function() {  
  $(".wrapper").fadeIn(); 
 });

 $(".close-modal").click(function() { 
     $(".wrapper").fadeOut(300); 
 });
});
```

```css
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

span {
 font-size: 20px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 border: solid 1px #000;
}


.wrapper {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100%; 
 background: #cdcdcd;
 padding: 30px 30px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000000;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    outline: 0; 
}

.wrapper-ins {
 height: calc(100vh - 60px);
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}


.close-modal {
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 99999;
    border: solid 2px #0082c3;
}
.close-modal::before {
 content: "X";
 color: #0082c3;
 display: block;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 46px;
}
.overflowHidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}





.swiper-container {
 height: inherit;
 width: inherit;
}

.gallery-top {
 float: left;
 height: inherit;
 width: calc(100% - 130px);
 margin-left: 130px;
}

.gallery-top .swiper-slide {
 align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
}

.gallery-top .swiper-slide img {
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 max-width: 100%;
 max-height: 100%;
}




.gallery-thumbs {
 /* max-height: 100%; */
 width: 100px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 0 0;
 background: #9c9c9c;
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 100;
 padding: 30px 0;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-wrapper {
 height: auto;
 min-height: 120px;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide {
 /* width: 100%; */
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 opacity: 0.4;
 position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

    overflow: hidden; /* dla zoom */
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide img {
 width:auto; 
 height:auto; 
 max-width: 90%; 
 max-height: 90%;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-thumb-active {
 opacity: 1;
}

.gallery-thumbs .swiper-slide-thumb-active:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 4px #0082c3;
}

.swiper-button-prev.gallery-thumbs-button,
.swiper-button-next.gallery-thumbs-button {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #fff;
 right: 0;
 left: 0;
 background-size: 20px 20px;
 margin-top: 0;
 height: 30px;
}

.swiper-button-prev.gallery-thumbs-button {
 top: 0;
}
.swiper-button-next.gallery-thumbs-button {
 top: initial;
 bottom: 0
}





.swiper-zoom {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translateX(-50%);
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 0; 
}
.zoomOut {
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-right: 2px;
}
.zoomIn {
 display: inline-block;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 line-height: 30px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: 700;
 margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://idangero.us/swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://idangero.us/swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="modal">start modal</span>


<div class="wrapper" style="display: none;">
<div class="wrapper-ins">

 <div class="close-modal-div">
  <div class="close-modal">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

 
  <div class="swiper-container gallery-thumbs">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/09/24/14/29/mac-459196_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/20/13/13/ipad-605439_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/09/08/32/digital-marketing-1725340_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/15/28/bar-621033_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/01/29/00/47/google-76517_960_720.png">
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/03/13/57/digital-marketing-1433427_960_720.jpg">
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next gallery-thumbs-button"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev gallery-thumbs-button"></div>
  
  </div>


  <div class="swiper-container gallery-top">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/09/24/14/29/mac-459196_960_720.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/01/20/13/13/ipad-605439_960_720.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/10/09/08/32/digital-marketing-1725340_960_720.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/02/02/15/28/bar-621033_960_720.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/01/29/00/47/google-76517_960_720.png" class="swiper-lazy">
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
   <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
    <img data-src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/06/03/13/57/digital-marketing-1433427_960_720.jpg" class="swiper-lazy">
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-button-white"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-button-white"></div>

  <div class="swiper-zoom">
   <div class="zoomOut">-</div>
   <div class="zoomIn">+</div>
  </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have one more problem. After enlarging the photo and calling the next slide, the previous slide does not disappear.

Comment: disable zoom working

code:
on: {
      slideChange: function () {
        //console.log("slideChange");
        galleryTop.zoom.out();
      }
     }